# Custom redirect user to specific page after register Observer in Magento 2 will just redirect after the cms page to the login page

Tags: event-observer, customer, customer-account, magento2.1.5, register

I have another problem with my custom observer module for account registration page redirect.

somehow it will successfully redirect to my custom cms thank you page after registration. but after that one, it will ask me to log in after registration. normally it should be automatically logged in instead of asking me to log in again.

Here's the codes:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="registerAfter" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RegisterAfter" />
</event>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/RegisterAfter.php

```
{
    protected $_responseFactory;

    protected $_redirect;

    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('thank-you-account-creation');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You does not login because of before execute of** `$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);` code your observer is redirect to your page.

if you  will check at [Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php#L309)

then you understand than c`ustomer_register_success **#L309**` event
then login function   [`$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php#L328)

### So,Solution,

You have two solution.

1.**Set Customer in session from observer**

```
protected $session;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
    Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    $this->session = $customerSession;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    /* Customer loggin in session */
    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);

    $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('thank-you-account-creation');
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
}
```

### Solution2:

Best solution,**set Customer session `setBeforeAuthUrl`** to `$customRedirectionUrl` and remove

`$customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('thank-you-account-creation');
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();`

and Must make sure `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` to **No** For solution 2

---

```
protected $session;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
    Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    $this->session = $customerSession;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('thank-you-account-creation');
    $this->session>setBeforeAuthUrl($successUrl); 
    return $this;

}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera, Thanks, I will try your code. and update to you once it is working.

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera, Thank you! it's working like charm!

Comment: 2nd Solution doesn't worked for me. I used Magento 2.4.4. can you tell me what the issue?\